# How to convert an object to be useful with a template in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, html, jakarta-ee, jstl

I have this template:

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${listObjects}">
     <div class="row" id="${row.id}">
         ${row.name}
     </div>
</c:foreach>
```

I have the class:

```
class ObjectX {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    public String getId() { return this.id; }
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

I have this DAO class:

```
class ObjectXDAO { public ArrayList<ObjectX> getObjects() { ... } }
```

What I need is to use the template to write the objects without change the template, how can I pass/convert the objects to be printable with the template? It's possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, all you need is the same structure in your objects, attributes "id" and "name" always! or it is going to fail, and include your template in many pages.

If you want, you can add to your template

```
<c:if test="typeList">
</c:if>
```

So you may include different types of lists to show in your template with more attributes. When you have your list, and a var as you have in your template, you can access to its attributes, don't forget all getters and setters.